# Django Serializer Object is not JSON Serializable

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

So I'm working on a website that uses Django and having trouble with the serializer. Here is the code:

```
class DataPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    value = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=15)
    sensor = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=list(Sensor.objects.all()))
    point = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=list(MapPoint.objects.all()))

    class Meta:
        model = DataPoint
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, attrs, instance=None):
        return DataPoint(value=attrs['value'], sensor=attrs['sensor'], point=attrs['point'])
```

My DataPoint model uses value as a decimal field, sensor as a foreign key, and point as another foreign key. I'm using the choice fields to fetch the objects that have been created but from the create function, I get a TypeError saying that (Sensor object) is not JSON serializable. I assume the same is happening for point but I am unsure of what to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First, you need to show the actual full traceback. But second, why are you using ChoiceField rather than a serializer relation?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable

Answer (score 0):

[According to choices](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#choicefield) is **A list of valid values, or a list of (key, display_name) tuples**. Specify field from Sensor and MapPoint objects or tuple (field, display_name):

```
list(Sensor.objects.values_list('id').all())
```

or, for example (if your model has **name** field)

```
list(Sensor.objects.values_list('id', 'name').all())
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is you are passing DataPoint class as the result of create function instead of DataPoint object. That is what the error means. And also `sensor` and `point` are primary keys. So you can use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` in the `serializer`.

Try this

```
class DataPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    value = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=15)
    sensor = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Sensor.objects.all())
    point = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=MapPoint.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = DataPoint
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data, instance=None):
        return DataPoint.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

**Note** : Since you are using model serializer, you don't need to specify `fields` or write definition for `create` or `update` functions. Model serializer itself finds the fields from the model and it should contains definitions for simple create and update functions. You can see the details [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer). Considfering these, your DataPointSerializer can be minimized to

```
class DataPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataPoint
        fields = "__all__"
```